# How does self.next = None get the next value of l1?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, mergesort, nonetype

I was working on one of the problems on Leetcode (problem 21). It asks me to merge two sorted linked lists and return it as a new list, and it gives pre-typed code like this.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution(object):
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1, l2):
        """
        :type l1: ListNode
        :type l2: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
```

I did some test before formally solving merging problem. I input l1 as following:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and I changed the code into:

```
class Solution(object):
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1, l2):
        print(l1.val)
        print(l1.next.val)
```

The output shows:

```
1
2
```

The part that confused me is how does function self.next get the next value of the ListNode that I input. In my understanding, self.next is set to None, so l1.next should equal to None, and None.val should go wrong. Could someone help me with this?

Here are two pictures that show the code, input, and output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueXbX.jpg)

Also, here is the link where I get my problem.
https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/#/description

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: I'm skeptical that you really passed a regular list like that into your function and got the output you quoted. `([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).val` produces an AttributeError.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `None` is the default value of `next` in a new `ListNode`. Other `ListNode`s can have other values assigned to `next`. Constructing a properly *linked* list of `ListNodes` involves assigning to each node's link parameter a reference to the next node:

```
l1 = ListNode(1)
l2 = ListNode(2)
l3 = ListNode(3)
l4 = ListNode(4)
l5 = ListNode(5)

l1.next = l2
l2.next = l3
l3.next = l4
l4.next = l5
```

Comment: Thank you for replying me. I did pass a regular list. I uploaded a pic in the question that shows my input and output, and the website that I got the problem. Maybe you can take a look at it. I understand your explanation, but what confuses me is I didn't set l1.next=l2, and it still gives me the second value when I type l1.next.val.

Comment: I can't reproduce your picture because I don't have an account on that site. I can only assume that when it says `[1,2,3,4,5]` it really means whatever linked-list representation they're using—that is, they already did `l1.next = l2` for you. Does it say `[1,2,3,4,5]` for the other languages?

Comment: That makes sense. They might change the input that I input into a certain format. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's pity that I don't have 15 reputations to vote your answer up.